# Count number of separators in CSV lines and print line number

Tags: awk, perl

We have a CSV file with more than 50000 lines.
This is only an example of the content:

```
Dcccrev,wefrwvfr,rfregt,wr4f,rfvrv,ecxwec,ecfrv,rfrf
Grge,gtgr,frfrv,gthtgv,gerg5tgvrt,rvrfvtg,tgt,frfrf,rfrf
Drfrfr,t,tgtg,rf,rgr,grtg,tgt,gtgtg,rg
.
.
.
```

My task is: when the number of separators "," in a line isn't equal to 7, then the line number must be printed.

Is it possible to create an awk or perl one liner for this task, without using echo or cat?

Comment: Please avoid [cross-posting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348148/awk-count-field-separator-in-csv-and-print-line-number)

Answer (score 1):

Try `awk -F, '{if (NF != 8) print NR}' file_name`. The -F, is a field seperator. With 7 commas there are 8 fields (NF Number Fields) and NR is (Number Record) the current record number.